# How to load module, class and attributes dynamically in python 3.5 package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am trying to build a package in Python 3.5

My code directory is as follows

```
mypackage
  |-- requirements.txt
  |-- setup.py
  |--vehicle
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- testdrive.py
      |-- cars
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- basecar_abstract_class.py
        |-- prius.py
        |-- volt.py
        |-- leaf.py
        |-- tesla.py
        |-- civic.py
        |-- there could be 100 of car classes ....
```

All cars extend abstract class defined in `basecar_abstract_class`. And `run` method is an abstract method, that must be defined in each cars class

`testdrive.py` code snippet is as follows:

```
class TestDrive(object):

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def runmycar(carname):
    # if tesla is passed as car name, then I want
    # it should first load tesla from cars module *DYNAMICALLY*
    # so that I can call tesla's run method defined in tesla.py 
    # vehicle.tesla.run()  ??
```

So my questions is: how to load module and class dynamically for asked car (also mentioned in the comment). Specifically, I want to know what are the changes (line adding/editing), I need to do in `testdrive.py` in order to achieve my goal

Currently my `__init__.py` in `cars` folder is just empty. Do you think, I need to put any code there too to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import importlib

import cars

def runmycar(car_name):
    #car_name = 'Tesla'
    module_name = '.' + car_name.lower()

    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name, 'cars')
    cls = getattr(mod, car_name)

    obj = cls()
    obj.run()
```